# How to create PDF for product description in Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, zend-pdf

I was searching the different Magento forums and extensions for this but i didn’t find anything.

What i want is to let my visitors to create a PDF file with image and description for the products they are interested.
With this will have the ability to save the product on its computer or print it.
This will be some kind of a printout offer.

The PDF must include the title, default image, description and price.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a default solution for this yet in magento, best thing to do is implement a PDF creator for PHP. Like [PDFLib](http://www.pdflib.com/products/)

Comment: Well I checked the structure of Magento,and I found some pdf generation code for generating Invoices.It has used ZEND_PDF class to generate the pdf.But as a new bee I don't much about the database structure of Magento so that I can accomplish it and get out what I want from the database.Please Help.